# How could I add a launch option to a URL (Steam, Shortcuts)

Tags: shortcuts, steam

I want to do this because my computer is horrible and would like to launch CS:GO in my .BAT script which improves framerate. How could I do this?
(not all launch options included due to clutter
I tried making a shortcut with `steam://rungameid/730 -high -threads 2`,
`"steam://rungameid/730" -high -threads 2` and I've even tried launching the game itself from the command prompt. `start "" "steam://rungameid/730 -high -threads 2"`, `start "" "steam://rungameid/730" -high -threads 2`, but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Okay turns out I'm extremely stupid. For anyone else wondering, just set the launch options on steam and it'll work just fine